# Proving an inequality with given conditions

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the inequality $P_n=a\left(\frac{1 − p}{p}\right)^n+b\leq \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^m$ for some $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ using the conditions $P_0=0$ and $P_T=1$ for $T=n+m$.

First I have tried to compute $a$ and $b$ using the given conditions and I get $a=\frac{p^{T}}{(1-p)^T-p^T}$ and $b=-a$. 
Using this in Formula it is $P_n=\frac{p^{T}}{(1-p)^T-p^T}\cdot \left(\frac{1 − p}{p}\right)^n-\frac{p^{T}}{(1-p)^T-p^T}=\frac{p^{n+m}}{(1-p)^{n+m}-p^{n+m}}\cdot (\left(\frac{1 − p}{p}\right)^n-1)$

I am not really sure how to go on from now.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Does $p\in (0,1)$?

Comment: Actually this is confusing: you say there exists some $a,b$ st for all $n$, $P_n$ is what you wrote on the first line, right? So what does $P_{n+m}=1$ means? For which $n$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is $p\in (0,1)$. I should have been more specific about the task,  the answer from below helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the last expression is $(\frac{p}{1-p})^m \frac{(\frac{p}{1-p})^n-1}{1+(\frac{p}{1-p})^{n+m}}$.

We work to show that $\frac{(\frac{p}{1-p})^n-1}{1+(\frac{p}{1-p})^{n+m}} <1$ for each $p \in (0,1)$. Please let me know if you require more general $p$.

Supposing that $\frac{p}{1-p}>1$ then it is easy to show $(\frac{p}{1-p})^n-1<1+(\frac{p}{1-p})^{n+m}$ because the RHS has grown wrt the LHS. If not, and $\frac{p}{1-p} \in (0,1)$, then it follows from the fact that $(\frac{p}{1-p})^n -1 \leq 1+ (\frac{p}{1-p})^{n+m}$ because LHS $\in (-1,0)$ and RHS $\in (1,2)$.

Comment: Yes, it should be $p\in (0,1)$. Sorry, I forgot to mention this part